# How to use generic Profile with Automapper and Asp.Net Core Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, automapper

I would like to create the .Net Core class library that will be contains following extension method:

```
public static class MyServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddMyService<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey>(this IServiceCollection services)
            where TUserDto : UserDto<TUserDtoKey>
            where TUser : User<TUserKey>
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(config =>
            {
                config.AddProfile<UserMappingProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey>>();
            });

            return services;
        }
    }
```

I have following Automapper Profile:

```
public class UserMappingProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey> : Profile 
        where TUserDto : UserDto<TUserDtoKey>
        where TUser : User<TUserKey>
    {
        public UserMappingProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<TUserDto, TUser>(MemberList.Destination)
                .ForMember(x => x.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.UserId));

            CreateMap<TUser, TUserDto > (MemberList.Source)
                .ForMember(x => x.UserId, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.Id));
        }
    }
```

These entities:

```
public class UserDto<TKey>
    {
        public TKey UserId { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

public class User<TKey>
    {
        public TKey Id { get; set; }

        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

public class MyUser : User<int>
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }

public class MyUserDto : UserDto<int>
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
```

If I try to use it like this:

```
services.AddMyService<MyUserDto, int, MyUser, int>();
```

I get this error:

> {System.ArgumentException: Cannot create an instance of
>   GenericMapping.Services.Mapping.UserMappingProfile`4[TUserDto,TUserDtoKey,TUser,TUserKey]
>   because Type.ContainsGenericParameters is true.    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceCheckThis()    at
>   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
>   wrapExceptions, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache)    at
>   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic, Boolean
>   wrapExceptions)    at
>   AutoMapper.Configuration.MapperConfigurationExpression.AddProfile(Type
>   profileType) in
>   C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\Configuration\MapperConfigurationExpression.cs:line
>   44    at
>   AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<AddAutoMapperClasses>g__ConfigAction|4(IMapperConfigurationExpression
>   cfg) in
>   C:\projects\automapper-extensions-microsoft-dependencyinjectio\src\AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line
>   83    at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.Build(Action`1 configure) in
>   C:\projects\automapper\src\AutoMapper\MapperConfiguration.cs:line 307 
>   at
>   AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection
>   services, Action`1 additionalInitAction, IEnumerable`1
>   assembliesToScan) in
>   C:\projects\automapper-extensions-microsoft-dependencyinjectio\src\AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection\ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:line
>   89    at
>   GenericMapping.Services.Extensions.MyServiceExtensions.AddMyService[TUserDto,TUserDtoKey,TUser,TUserKey](IServiceCollection
>   services) in
>   C:\Projects\GenericMapping\GenericMapping.Services\Extensions\MyServiceExtensions.cs:line
>   14    at GenericMapping.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection
>   services) in C:\Projects\GenericMapping\GenericMapping\Startup.cs:line
>   33}

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: AM supports SourceLink, so it should be easy to go through the code in order to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The root cause of your issue is the incorrect usage of the *AddAutoMapper* extension method. This method scans assemblies for profiles (and other AutoMapper components) and registers an *IMapper* component in the DI container using the configuration found. (I suggest you taking a look at [its sources](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/blob/v5.0.1/src/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L60) to understand what's going on exactly under the hood.)

You get the exception because *AddAutoMapper* finds the *UserMappingProfile* class but has no clue how to instantiate it as it has 4 open type arguments.

The easiest way of resolving the issue is to make your generic profile class abstract and to subclass it with the desired type arguments:

```
public abstract class UserMappingProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey> : Profile
    where TUserDto : UserDto<TUserDtoKey>
    where TUser : User<TUserKey>
{
    public UserMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TUserDto, TUser>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.UserId));

        CreateMap<TUser, TUserDto>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(x => x.UserId, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.Id));
    }
}

public class UserMappingProfile : UserMappingProfile<MyUserDto, int, MyUser, int> { }
```

Now you don't need *MyServiceExtensions* at all, just a `services.AddAutoMapper()` call and your configuration will be picked up automatically.

However, if you insist on doing the configuration using your own extension methods, you have to avoid *AddAutoMapper* as it's intended to be called only once. Instead of scanning assemblies for *Profile* classes, you can provide your own registration logic. An example using the builder pattern:

```
public class UserMappingProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey> : Profile
    where TUserDto : UserDto<TUserDtoKey>
    where TUser : User<TUserKey>
{
    public UserMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TUserDto, TUser>(MemberList.Destination)
            .ForMember(x => x.Id, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.UserId));

        CreateMap<TUser, TUserDto>(MemberList.Source)
            .ForMember(x => x.UserId, opts => opts.MapFrom(x => x.Id));
    }
}

public interface IMapperConfigurationBuilder
{
    IMapperConfigurationBuilder UseProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey>()
        where TUserDto : UserDto<TUserDtoKey>
        where TUser : User<TUserKey>;
}

public static class MyServiceExtensions
{
    private class MapperConfigurationBuilder : IMapperConfigurationBuilder
    {
        public HashSet<Type> ProfileTypes { get; } = new HashSet<Type>();

        public IMapperConfigurationBuilder UseProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey>()
            where TUserDto : UserDto<TUserDtoKey>
            where TUser : User<TUserKey>
        {
            ProfileTypes.Add(typeof(UserMappingProfile<TUserDto, TUserDtoKey, TUser, TUserKey>));
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static IMapperConfigurationBuilder AddMyMapper(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var builder = new MapperConfigurationBuilder();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationProvider>(sp => new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var profileType in builder.ProfileTypes)
                cfg.AddProfile(profileType);
        }));

        services.AddScoped<IMapper>(sp => new Mapper(sp.GetRequiredService<IConfigurationProvider>(), sp.GetService));
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Then the mapping profile registration would look like this:

```
services.AddMyMapper()
    .UseProfile<MyUserDto, int, MyUser, int>();
```